# how to deterministically generate a key from a passphrase with nodejs crypto module

Tags: node.js, key, bitcoin, cryptojs

I want to generate a key pair, in NodeJS v10.16.3, using the crypto module, from the hash of a passphrase or seed.

I'm getting a public and private key and I'm able to sign with it.

They look like this;

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaScBwOHQRRIDzPb3cnz3TZfHYOG7
pM7M8PkZFq7DjElFUrkavQf9NSopuJcIZ0EOmlQq8jPLbLdHoUO9M9a1Pw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The code to create this;
Basically from the doc found here; 
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback

```
var seed = "a very long and random passphrase or seed";
let sha256 = require('js-sha256');
seed = sha256(seed);


const { generateKeyPair } = require('crypto');
generateKeyPair('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'P-256',
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem',
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
    passphrase: seed
  }
}, (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  console.log('Node Private : ', privateKey);
  console.log('Node public : ', publicKey);

  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile("test.dat", privateKey, function(err) {
      if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
  }); 

});
```

How can I generate  a keypair using a seed so I can reproduce that same key again? The seed I am using is not changing but the key is.

If I want to create addresses by hashing the public key. I wouldn't be able to reproduce the same hash.

I want to do something similar to what is done with crypto wallet right now.